# How to get a file path using tkinter askopenfilename or other command?

Tags: python, tkinter, pymupdf

I'm building a simple app, where it converts pdf to png.

When I use:

```
pdf_name = askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title="Selecionar Arquivos")
```

I get:

```
print(pdf_name)

('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Apps/Python/Conversor img to pdf/file.pdf',)
```

So, the ask is:

How do I get this type?

```
print(pdf_name)

'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Apps/Python/Conversor img to pdf/file.pdf'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do that.

First

```py
pdf_name = askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title="Selecionar Arquivos")
print(pdf_name[0])
```

Second, Instead of `askopenfilenames`, you should try `askopenfilename`.

Also, Not Forget To Import this `from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename`.

```py
pdf_name = askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Selecionar Arquivos")
print(pdf_name)
```

The output is same for both

```py
'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Apps/Python/Conversor img to pdf/file.pdf'
```

Comment: @PauloRoberto You can vote it too.

Comment: Thank you a lot, man. Thats exactly what I needed

Comment: @PauloRoberto Welcome, bro.